# cat всем файлам последовательно в одной директории

Tags: linux

Как запустить cat одной командой сразу всех текстовых файлов, находящихся в определенной директории вместо запуска по отдельности?
`find /directory -name \*.txt | sort | xargs -I{} cat {}`

или если например в директории файлы не только *.txt
`find /directory -name \* | sort | xargs -I{} cat {}`
работает, но последняя строчка предыдущего файла сбивается в одну с первой следующего. Как правильно?

Comment: слушай, ну это же можно сделать 1000-ей способов! например, `for i in \`ls -1p *pm | grep -v /\`; do cat $i; done`. или `cat \`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name '*pm'\``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Работает, но последняя строчка предыдущего файла сбивается в одну с первой следующего

Cкорей всего файлы не текстовые в строгом смысле этого слова (на последней строке нет перевода строки).

Правильным решением было бы их подправить, например с помощью `sed -i -e '$a\' <файл>`.

Если нужно работать именно с такими битыми файлами, то можно использовать это выражение прямо вместо `cat`'а:

```
find /dir -type f -iname '*.txt' -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 sed '$a\'
```

Comment: про отсутствие перевода в последней строке мысль верная, однако `find /dir -type f -iname '*.txt' -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 sed '$a\'` выдает список файлов *.txt, а не читает их. если сделать `find /mnt/hgfs/blocks/test -type f -iname '*.*' -print0 | sort -z | xargs -r0 sed '$a\'`, то работает. все дело в маске поиска наименования файла. как сделать так, чтоб в фильтр попадали только *.txt и *.lst и никакие другие? `-iname '*.*t'` ?

Comment: @Bl0wfish, не особо понял, что не работает в первом случае, нудаладно... матчить пару расширений ИМХО проще с помощью `regex'а`: `-regex '.*\.\(lst\|txt\)'`. Но можно и с помощью логических условий: `-iname '*.txt' -o -iname '*.lst'`.

Answer (score 2):

1. получить список всех файлов в каталоге (в алфавитном порядке):

   ```
   $ ls *
   ```
2. получить тот же список для файлов, имеющих суффикс `.txt`:

   ```
   $ ls *.txt
   ```
3. вывести содержимое тех же самых файлов можно программой *cat*:

   ```
   $ cat *.txt
   ```
4. битость файлов (проявляющуюся в отсутствии перевода строки в последней строке) можно исправить «на лету», например, примитивнейшей программой, понимаемой интерпретатором *sed*:

   ```
   $ sed '$s/$/\n/' *.txt
   ```